# Foreach key where the object[key] meets a precondition

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to access all 2nd level elements of a nested object that meet a criteria without knowing the first level key.

For example:

```
myObject = {
   foo: {
      element_one : 1,
      element_two : 1,
      ...
   },
   bar: {
      element_one : 3,
      element_two : 4,
      ...
   },
   buzz: {
      element_one : 99,
      element_two : 100,
      ...
   },
   ...
}
```

In the example above I wanted to be able to efficiently grab all 1st level keys where `myObject.<any_key>.element_one === some_number`.

One obvious solution is to iterate through the list and check each element but with multiple calls to this function this becomes computationally costly. As a backup I could create a new object where the keys = element_one and use it as a reference.

But I'm curious to know if there is a better way to handle this?

EDIT:
I don't have prior knowledge about max value for the elements may be.

Comment: Yes, iterating is the only solution for the data structure you have chosen. If you really need to do this often, maintain a separate data structure that has a `Map` from numbers to lists of keys (or of the objects themselves). This would have the best performance for the "multiple calls" you described. I can't think of anything else, as you didn't state any other properties of the structure.

Comment: To be clear, you'll have iterate (visiting each key), a process that cannot be better than O(n).  @Bergi is suggesting caching that result, so you can avoid redoing the work over m invocations, but note that O(m*n) = O(n).

Answer (score 0):

something like would work:

```
var obj = <YOUR_OBJ>
var final_keys = [];

for(key in obj)
{
 if(a[key].element_one == 1){
   final_keys.push(key);
 }
}
console.log(final_keys);
```

Comment: OP already knows that: "*One obvious solution is to iterate through the list and check each element*"

Comment: I think you can use the the condition with the Object.values() and check with array indexOf function. For more please let me know what type of condition you want here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys` to get an array of the 1st level keys of your object and use `Array.prototype.filter` to filter among the 1st level keys, for which second level key has the specified number:

```js
myObject = {
   foo: {
      element_one : 1,
      element_two : 1
      },
   bar: {
      element_one : 3,
      element_two : 4
     },
   buzz: {
      element_one : 99,
      element_two : 100
   }
   
} 
console.log(Object.keys(myObject).filter(key => myObject[key].element_one === 99));
```

Comment: OP already knows that: "*One obvious solution is to iterate through the list and check each element*"

Comment: Interesting comment. But unfortunately I don't have the prior knowledge of what the range of numbers element_one can be. With that in mind, maintaining a 2nd data structure may be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm going to give 2 different solutions.

1) you get the **array of matching keys**

2) you get a **new object with the matching keys (and its associated values)**

```js
const myObject = {
   foo: {
      element_one : 1,
      element_two : 1,
   },
   bar: {
      element_one : 3,
      element_two : 4,
   },
   dogs: {
      element_one : 1,
      element_two : 4,
   },
   buzz: {
      element_one : 1,
      element_two : 100,
   },
}

const matchingKeys = Object.keys(myObject).filter(key => {
 return myObject[key].element_one === 1
})

// 1st solution: if you want the matching keys only
console.log(matchingKeys)

const objectWithMatchingKeys = Object.keys(myObject).reduce((acc, val) => {
  if (myObject[val].element_one === 1) acc[val] = myObject[val]
  return acc
}, {})

// 2nd solution: if you want the object WITH matching keys
console.log(objectWithMatchingKeys)
```

you can make any of the above solutions extendable/reusable by replacing the hard coded keys (e.g. element_one) as a function param in a helper function!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your responses.
I think considering I don't have any control or knowledge over the min/max values of any of the elements and they are not necessarily in order; Bergi and RK_oo7's comments are correct. The most efficient solution is to iterate through the list once and cache the element values for the future.

Something like this this:

```
var elementIndex = {};
Object.entries(myObject).forEach(([key, val]) => {
  if (val.element_one in elementIndex) {
     elementIndex[val.element_one].push(key);
  } else {
     elementIndex[val.element_one] = [key];
  }
});
```